# Wireless router/livecd distro?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, livecd

I've got an [old IBM r51](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:R51), which aside from a dead hard drive, and unreliable keyboard, and a working [intel 2100 wireless adaptor.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_PRO/Wireless_LAN_2100_3B_Mini_PCI_Adapter) I'm looking for a linux live cd or usb that i can connect into an existing wired network. Ideally i want to be able to administer it over web or through a GUI, and if possible get the 2100 working in master mode.

Additionally, considering it has a bunch of usb ports, the ability to work as a nas, with the same prerequisites would be appreciated.

I have *some* degree of knowledge of linux, so failing a prebuilt solution, suggestions on config of a customised system might be an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a router, take a look at [M0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) or [IPcop](http://www.ipcop.org/), whilst both of these are mainly advertised as a firewall appliance, they should be able to do what you want and act as a full router.

For a Nas - Look at [Freenas](http://www.freenas.org)

Comment: FreeNAS livecds: http://www.freenas.org/index.php?option=com_versions&Itemid=51

Comment: the iso link for m0n0wall - http://m0n0.ch/wall/download.php?file=cdrom-1.236.iso

Answer (score 2):

Vyatta has a Linux-based router that you can run from a bootable cd. I don't know if it supports wireless.

Comment: Vyatta isos: http://www.vyatta.com/downloads/index.php

This is probably the way to go, I'm pretty sure the live cd has the necessary drivers for that wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [OpenWRT on x86](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=20478).  The link includes instructions for making a bootable USBkey.  There are packages that provide web administration but they may not include all the functionality you're looking for; however, you can administer all aspects via SSH.

There is an [x86 DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/X86) but the free version is limited (no wifi), and the page claims USB is not supported in either free or registered versions.

Comment: note these distros are designed as 3rd-party firmware replacements for home routers.  running them on x86 may not be well-supported.